Visual Studio Code Gradle Tasks not up to date with settings.json and tasks.json
I have put a custom gradle task to the list of tasks using the following snippet in the settings.json
    {
        "gradle.javaDebug": {
            "tasks": [
                "bootRun"
            ],
            "clean": true
        }
    }

But, I wanted to enhance it with custom environment variables, so I moved it to tasks.json:
    {
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "bootRun2",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "./gradlew",
            "args": [
                "bootRun",
                "-Dspring.profiles.active=local",
                "--debug-jvm"
            ],
            "options": {
                "env": {
                    "google.recaptcha.key.skipCaptcha": "true",
                    "jmix.search.search-index-name-prefix": "beg_hummli_",
                    "jmix.search.elasticsearch.login": "monitoring",
                    "jmix.search.elasticsearch.url": "https://es.dev.beg-verwaltung.de",
                    "keycloakservice.config.keycloakPassword": "%44mNPkv&qU*pH",
                    "jmix.search.elasticsearch.password": "cHtt%J7P#D*H*#"
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "kill-java"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "kill-java",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "pkill",
            "args": [
                "java"
            ]
        }
    ]
    }

Now I removed the block from settings.json again, but still, I can see the task in the Tasks/application in Visual Studio Code. The new one is not there. I tried reimporting the project, restarting VS-Code, Reloading all gradle projects etc., but it seems to have an old snapshot of my tasks being displayed in VS Code. How can I get the task from tasks.json to be displayed correctly and make the previous one disappear?
